# Prove double Integral is 0

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $D$ the region formed by all the points $(x,y)$ such that $-\phi(x) \leq y \leq\phi(x), a\leq x \leq b$ where $\phi$ is continuous non-negative in $[a,b]$. Let $f(x,y)$ on $D$ such that $f(x,y) = -f(x,-y) \forall (x,y) \in D$. Show that $$\int\int_D f(x,y)dA = 0$$

**Proof**: $$\begin{equation}\int\int_D f(x,y)dA = \int_{a}^{b}\int_{-\phi(x)}^{\phi(x)}f(x,y)dydx\\ = \int_{a}^{b}\int_{\phi(x)}^{-\phi(x)}-f(x,-y)dydx = 0\end{equation}$$
I skipped to take out the constant $-1$ from the integral but I argue that the Integral is bounded by $-\phi(x)$ to $\phi(x)$ but at the same time is bounded by $\phi$ to $-\phi$, so it must be $0$.

I think that there is a big hole in this proof or it is not well proved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split the y integral up across the x axis, you’ll get
$\int_{-\phi(x)}^{0} f(x,y) dy 
+\int_{0}^{\phi(x)} f(x,y) dy 
$
You can then change the variable y to say $-y_1$. Applying this new variable to all aspects of the integral, you get 
$$\int_{-\phi(x)}^{0}  f(x,y) dy = \int_{\phi(x)}^{0}  f(x, -y_1)(-dy_1)= \int_{\phi(x)}^{0}  f(x, y_1)dy_1 = -\int^{\phi(x)}_{0}  f(x, y_1)dy_1$$
which cancels exactly with the positive to result in 0.

Answer (score 1):

I would split
$\int_{-\phi(x)}^{\phi(x)}
$
into
$\int_{-\phi(x)}^{0}
+\int_{0}^{\phi(x)}
$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a hole. You have to split into two integrals.

$$
\iint_Df(x,y)\,dxdy=\int\limits_a^b\left(\int\limits_0^{\phi(x)}f(x,y)\,dy\right)\,dx+\int\limits_a^b\left(\int\limits_{-\phi(x)}^{0}f(x,y)\,dy\right)\,dx
$$
Changing $y\to -w$ in the second integral above, you get
$$
\int\limits_a^b\left(\int\limits_0^{\phi(x)}f(x,y)\,dy\right)\,dx-\int\limits_a^b\left(\int\limits_{\phi(x)}^{0}f(x,-w)\,dw\right)\,dx
$$
$$
=\int\limits_a^b\left(\int\limits_0^{\phi(x)}f(x,y)\,dy\right)\,dx-\int\limits_a^b\left(\int\limits_{0}^{\phi(w)}f(x,w)\,dw\right)\,dx=0
$$
where we used the given symmetry conditions for the last equality.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the change of variable $(x,y) \to (x,-y)$. You will see immediately that the integral equals its negative.